# Vaadin 24 - Async render call seems to be "hang"

Tags: vaadin24

e.g.
while current is UI.
After some async service done, and we want to push relevant change to component. e.g. model

```
current.access(new Command() {
      @Override
      public void execute() {
          getElement().executeJs("this.widget.refresh(window.JSON.parse($0))", model);
      }
});
```

no change on screen until doing e.g. mouse click event on page.
Tried to use the accessSynchronously also. same problem. Changes appear only after 'touching' the screen.

no error/exceptions in console or logs.

Use from component that created using the @JavaScript annotation.
working synchronously works fine, but when trying to be asych, seems that render stack somewhere.
tried with Vaadin 24.10.1 and 24.3.3

Comment: do you have `@Push` annotation on your view? Have you tried `current.access(....); current.push();`, sometimes this works for me

Comment: Thanks. wasn't aware of Push annotation. I wonder what sense it is make from API perspective. Is there any case to use UI.access not in order to interrupt from another thread?

Comment: I believe it's one step above - there are many cases where no usage of UI.access are needed in the app at all. Therefore this push connection between server and frontend/javascript does not need to be opened in the first place. This is my assumption at least

Comment: Does it work now using `@Push`? if yes then I'll write up a longer answer than my comment

Comment: yes it is working on non production builds. On production mode at 24.3.3 nothing from my component is rendering. but does with 24.1.10. i wonder what and if has any connection to this annotation. so on 24.3.3 After change Push to manual and add push() in relevant place it work exactly like in debug mode. really wired. Thank you so very much. Please add your answer so i can set it as the solution

Comment: huh thats weird. I haven't worked with v24 yet so I'm as confused as you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to modify the UI from an async Thread* using `ui.access(() -> {...})`, then you need to have the `@Push` notification on your View (or one of its "parent" routerLayout-views).

Otherwise that ui modification will show up only after your next server roundtrip (any user interaction in the UI -> button click, etc).

You can use `@Push(PushMode.MANUAL)` if you intend to invoke `ui.push()` after each call of `ui.access(..)`.
Or you can simply use `@Push` which will default to PushMode.AUTOMATIC - automatically pushing any changes that were made when the ui-lock from a `ui.access(..)` call is lifted

Sidenote: Even though I mostly use automatic pushmode, it has occurred to me that I'd still need to call `ui.push()` sometimes for it to work. I am not sure if that was a bug or an intentional edge-case.

---

* or within e.g. a click listener of a `Button` if you want the modification to show before the whole clicklistener has completed (most common use case for me)

---

PS: you can simplify your code with a lambda expression:

```
current.access(() -> getElement().executeJs("this.widget.refresh(window.JSON.parse($0))", model));
```